# Script loading before jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a script in my custom meta-boxes and wish to use jQuery, the problem is that the admin page loads my script **before** it loads jQuery, rendering my script useless, when I inspect the page it looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // use $
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and then the rest of the document loads, with header and all that sweet jazz. Is there anyway I can get my `<script>jquery here</script>` load AFTER my jQuery gets loaded?

Comment: How is it happening? I mean, as long as jQuery is included before your script, it cannot be execute before it.

Comment: Im not sure why, Cant find where it puts the jQuery in queue

Answer (score 1):

you have to insert your script into this way:

```
function load_custom_scripts()
{    
  wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', 'COMPLETE_PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT');
}

do_action ( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_scripts' );
```

I suggest you to put all of your custom scripts in a separate JS file and then load to the WP.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you cannot use jQuery until it has loaded..

But you can use plain JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 // $ should be available
}, false);
```

Comment: The loaded script is outside of the `<!DOCTYPE html>` element meaning the page rendered contains invalid markup so this would not help...